# input filtering capacitor design

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, capacitance

How to make input filtering capacitance circuit (capacitor bank) if values of one capacitor are not enough to handle with voltage and capacitance? For example, calculated input capacitor value for AC-to-DC converter 1.4 millifarad 640 V.

[image: Schematic of example]

Comment: which caps? Normally a passive, active or switched reactive balancer is used similar to a Lithium battery balancer.  The choice must depend on the % of VAR imbalance

Comment: electrolytic capacitors. Could you give any solution in similar examples. Main purpose of question is to understand how to make capacitor bank if values of one capacitor are not enough.

Comment: What is your budget? qty? for this string or single cap component/module and what is spec for ESR?  This is a critical tradeoff.

Comment: Because they do exist for $200 @1.6 mOhm

Comment: or $300 at 0.6mOhm

Comment: No idea?  € 141.61

Comment: Budget and seize do not play a key role.

Comment: Could you provide links to these caps?

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/62?k=1.4+mF&k=&pkeyword=1.4+mF&pv2049=u1200%C2%B5F&pv2049=u1400%C2%B5F&pv1293=152&pv1293=39&pv1293=40&pv1293=41&pv1293=43&pv1293=44&pv1293=161&pv1293=46&pv1293=47&pv1293=48&pv1293=170&pv1293=2&pv1293=87&pv1293=5&pv1293=6&pv1293=7&pv1293=135&pv1293=8&pv1293=9&pv1293=10&pv1293=11&pv1293=86&pv1293=16&pv1293=18&pv1293=22&sf=0&FV=ffe0003e&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Comment: What's your project called?

Comment: Pulse-step-modulation, when identical power supplies are connected in series to obtain high voltage, usually several kilovolts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They [do exist](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/epcos-tdk/B25620B0158K883/495-7229-ND/5810157) if you look under Caps, Film

[image]

Categories  Capacitors
Film Capacitors
Manufacturer    EPCOS (TDK)
Series  B2562
Packaging ?     Bulk ?
Part Status     Active  88 Stock
Capacitance     1500µF
Tolerance   ±10%
Voltage Rating - AC     -
Voltage Rating - DC     900V
Dielectric Material     Polypropylene (PP), Metallized
Operating Temperature   -55°C ~ 75°C
Mounting Type   Chassis, Stud Mount
Package / Case  Radial, Can
Size / Dimension    4.567" Dia (116.00mm)
Height - Seated (Max)   7.126" (181.00mm)
Termination     Threaded, Female
Lead Spacing    1.969" (50.00mm)
Applications    DC Link, DC Filtering

Comment: Jesus, I would be pretty worried about being too near a capacitor charged up to 1kJ

Comment: Only for the brave at heart making xx kW GTI's