# Capacitors in series, equivalent capacitance to reduce voltage rating

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply

For example, I need 100uF 60V capacitor for filtering in power supply. The DC source is about 40V, but I have 400uF 20V capacitors.

If I arrange four of them in series I got in total 100 uF and each capacitor has a voltage drop of 10 volts according DC source.

Thus, can I replace 100uF 60V capacitors with four 400uF 20V capacitors in series? Are 20V capacitors OK?

How can I design symmetrizing resistors for it?

Comment: What's the highest DC leakage value for the 20 volt capacitors. If you don't know then read the data sheet. If you can't find a data sheet buy one capacitor rated for the correct voltage.

Comment: Yes, you are right if it is available why not to buy cap that I need. However, recently I read research paper about high voltage power supplies, to filter out rectified voltage they use capacitor bank with value 1.2 mF, voltage in circuit was 800V. So, how to design such kind capacitor bank is purpose of my question. Yes, there are some specific terms in this question, but I need at least some general vision how to design such a capacitor bank.

Comment: This isn't really a discussion site.

Comment: Recently I asked this question another way, I closed it as answered. But this issue emerges again https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396887/input-filtering-capacitor-design

Comment: OVP Protection and BMS battery balancing on high voltage strings of DC are similar issues often performed by Active voltage limiters for the mismatched voltage and expected current flow and mismatched tolerances after aging. In your case 4 MOV’s may work but depends on startup current surge.  Wouldn’t you rather get the right parts?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is better to choose right parts if arranging in series has so much special terms and consequences. Just, I tried to understand this topic better that's why I raised this question. Thank you, @TonyEErocketscientist.

Comment: Try out Falstad's cct simulator and put real values unbalanced worst case tolerance for each C,ESR in series with a step current. http://tinyurl.com/y9egwc35  You might make it work no sweat or have really poor caps or great caps

Answer (score 4):

You will have to include a parallel resistor-ladder to stabilize the node voltages. The resistor values must be high enough for the low-pass to be effective
$$f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi RC} $$
and low enough to ensure a save operating point (smaller than the capacitors leakage).
This will cost you some additional power.

Comment: Could you join discussion under question? Please, read my comment. Is this approach (arranging in series)  applicable in higher values also?

Comment: @MaxRock yes sure you can do that with high voltages. I don't expect the reaistors to cause any trouble, however, you have to check the capacitors AC-behaviour for switched applications. Electrolytic caps (you said you'd use those?) are pretty bad for stabilising fast transients.

Comment: What kind caps are more applicable for this issue?

Comment: @MaxRock there are quite some options: http://www.ti.com/jp/lit/pdf/slyt639

Comment: The R values required to balance 20% C tolerance is ineffective, if it were HV Caps, Zener like parts are needed for OVP, here just use the right parts  and keep mind when C degrades in value with temp, it will accelerate faster to failure.  -1 for suggesting simple R balancing on large C’s, typically chosen for low ESR parts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have 4 400uF/20V capacitor. to make a 100uF capacitance, you could make a series circuit from them and for symmetrizing you have to make one 1Mohm resistor parallel with each 400uF capacitor.
With this combination, you have made a circuit that is some how equivalent with a 100uF/80V capacitor that could tolerate 80V at most. For reliability issues, you can just use 80% of this therefore your circuit must not be under more than 0.8 * 80 == 64V. 
Due to your need that is a 100uF/60V capacitor it seems OK but be careful that reducing the number of component will increase the reliability and production costs and this solution is just good when you have strong reasons. For example, the 100uF/60V capacitor is too big for the system case or big for tolerating g-shocks.
Moreover the capacitance and tolerated voltage of the capacitors have direct relation with ambient temperature and you have to support it in your design.

In the desktop PC switching power supplies, you can see two series 220uF~680uF/200V capacitors at its high voltage region (input == 220V AC). These capacitors are also symmetrized with two 1 Mega Ohm resistors and manufactured in very high volume with enough reliability.
Desktop SPSS has used this combination because for reducing the 100Hz ripple of the DC output, it needs biggest capacitor that is able to be fitted in the case and tolerate 400V. Regulated value of the 220V AC input line voltage is around 308V DC and caps must work under it properly therefore the combination of caps in the desktop SPSS must be able to tolerate 400V (80% of it is 320V that is near enough to 308V DC)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, as you say 4x 400uF caps in series gives 100uF and if they are rated at 20V each then total rating will be 80V, which is above your spec so it should be fine.

Comment: Wrong because you haven't accounted for the different leakage resistances on each. Three might have ten times more leakage than the remaining one and this will mean two thirds of the voltage will appear across just one capacitor. Did you not read the bit in the question about symmetrizing resistors?

Comment: Nope that wasn't present in the question when I posted my answer. Do you know a method for calculating where exactly the voltage will be seen?